# Error using react-toastify, toast do not view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
> at useToastContainer (react-toastify.esm.js?146c:296)
> at ToastContainer (react-toastify.esm.js?146c:954)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14563)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:15063)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17820)
> at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17860)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:149)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:199)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:256)
> at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17107)

My class

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

export class ViewAllGraphs extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.notify = this.notify.bind(this);
    }
    notify() {
        console.log("call notify");
        toast("Wow so easy !");
    }

    addGraph(id) {
        console.log("addGraph");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(toast);
        toast.configure();
        this.notify();
    }
```

and render method return

```
<img onClick={this.addGraph.bind(this, item.id)} src={`data:image/png;base64,${item.image}`} />
```

I am new in js, how i can call toast by click on an image?

My Console log

> addGraph ViewAllGraphs.js?5897:52  6011412ff65b72973fc0f495

> ViewAllGraphs.js?5897:53//it's id  ƒ toast(content, options) {
> return dispatchToast(content, mergeOptions(TYPE.DEFAULT, options)); }

> ViewAllGraphs.js?5897:54 call notify ViewAllGraphs.js?5897:41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remember to include the `<ToastContainer />` in your render. Here is a working code for you along with a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-easley-z52hd?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.notify = this.notify.bind(this);
  }
  notify() {
    console.log("call notify");
    toast.success("This is a test success", {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
      autoClose: 2000,
      hideProgressBar: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Click the image
        <br />
        <img onClick={this.notify} src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const AlertToast = () => {
  const notify = () =>
    toast("This is an alert message. This is an alert message.");

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={notify}>Notify !</button>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AlertToast;
```

Comment: I don't need button, i  want to understand why         toast("Wow so easy !"); is not work

Comment: your console.log("call notify"); is printed when you click on the img tag? if your function called correctly then. I think you need to add the <ToastContainer /> in the render.